# Deleting rows from a database using a foreach. (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, database

Alright so a disclaimer. I am sorry if there is already a solution to this (probably it's since this is a simple question).

I am making my own wordpress plugin and it saves information in a database.
I have a button that deletes everything using `TRUNCATE`

I am now trying to make it so I can delete a single row.

The code I have so far is:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $tablename, ARRAY_A);

//Counts the amount of rows
$count = "SELECT COUNT('id') FROM " . $tablename;
$numberOfRows = $wpdb->get_var($count);
//Echo's the amount of rows
//echo $numberOfRows;

//Checks if the amount of rows is more then 0
if ($numberOfRows > 0) {

    //Loops through the array $result as index 0 > $numberOfRows and then grabs the value out of those
    foreach($result as $person=>$value) {
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tbody>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<strong>id:</strong> " . $value["id"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . " <strong>- Name:</strong> " . $value["naam"] . " " . $value["achternaam"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . " <strong>email:</strong> " . $value["email"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . " <strong>telefoon:</strong> " . $value["telefoon"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . " <strong>message:</strong> " . $value["Message"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . " <strong>subject:</strong> " . $value["subject"] . "</td>" . "<br>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
        ?>
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $actual_link?>">
        <button name="DeleteButton">Delete</button>
        </form>

        <?php
        $resultId = $value["id"];
        if(isset($_POST["DeleteButton"])){
            $wpdb->delete($tablename, array( 'id' => $resultId) );
        }
    }
} else {
   echo "0 results";
}
```

I've also tried `$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM wp_informatie WHERE ID=" . $value["id"]`

But it keeps deleting every row.
My logic is that if it says 1 at id it will also be 1 when I press the delete button, what I am thinking is that because it is a array when I press the button it deletes everything.

It would be amazing if someone can answer this or link me something with an explanation and answer.

Comment: What does `$actual_link` look like?

Comment: `$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";`               
I use this because I had problem with PHP_SELF .